# Binding Height of window to Wight and W to H

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

```
Height="{Binding Source=Self, Path=Width}"   
Width="627"
```

This doesn't work.  To begin, `Height` gets a length of `Width`, but when I am changing `Width`, `Height` doesn't want to change.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I really don't understand what are you trying to do. Anyway see if this helps Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=WindowName}"

Comment: I try crete behavior as has PokersStars Windows, they dond change first parametr without second, for  example

Answer (score 1):

`Height` and `Width` define the size you want your element to be.

During the rendering of your visuals, the available size for your element is calculated in relation to everything else, and the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` are updated.

`Height` and `Width` do not change as a result of this calculation, but if `Height` and `Width` are changed, the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` are recalculated.

Change your `Binding` path to use the `ActualWidth` and you should end up with a square.

```
Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Source should be RelativeSource

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RelativeSource` binding:

```
Height="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
```

Comment: It is legal? As i know Mode mean other thing, if more detaily it is mean way of Binding (OneTime, TwoWay and e.g). I may be wrong with it.

Comment: please pay attention that Mode here is a property inside the relative source. the mode you are talking about has a different meaning then this one